# Best solution to maxLength being ignored

Tags: html, mobile, browser, maxlength

```
<input type="TEXT" name="smth" maxLength="19 "id="smthid">
```

Works fine. But I came across situation where user could input more than 19 characters. (mobile browser on xperia, while some other phones work fine...)

 what is the best solution to tackle this problem

Comment: That depends on why you primarilly need this, is it to help the user not to enter too much text, or protect the server from recieving too much text?

Comment: @Guffa both. Lets say user has to input social security number, it helps a lot to be limited to maxlength, also servervise could be usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to tackle problems like that, depending on what experience you want for the user, for example:

- Add a Javascript that will listen to the `keypress` event, and remove characters if the text is too long.
- Add a Javascript that validates the form on submit, and doesn't let the user submit the form with too long values.
- Reject the input on the server side if the value is too long, and send the user back to the form.
- Cut down the value on the server side it if is too long.

Each method has its own drawbacks, either in its complexity or its user experience.

Note that you can never fully rely on the code in the browser to protect the server from invalid input, you should always do the necessary validation on the server side.